# Generalized method of moments versus standard least squares estimation

Tags: r, method-of-moments, generalized-moments

I was thinking that in a very standard case such as a simple linear model with iid errors and no endogeneity, I would get the same results using the a simple least square estimate (such as provided by `lm()` in R) and a simple GMM estimator with an identity matrix as the weighting matrix and the matrix of regressors as instruments.

I've just run the following simulation in R to compare the results of the `lm()` function and of the `gmm()` function :

```
> library("gmm")
> set.seed(1234567)
> N  <- 1000
> dd  <- data.frame(id = 1:N)
> dd$u  <- rnorm(N)
> dd$x  <- 1 + rnorm(N)
> dd$y  <- 1 + dd$x + dd$u
> m1  <- lm(y ~ x, data = dd)
> m2  <- gmm(y ~ x, x = ~ x,  wmatrix = "ident", data = dd)
```

I've got the same coefficients but I don't have exactly the same standard errors :

```
> coefficients(m1)
(Intercept)           x 
  1.0273856   0.9690455 
> coefficients(m2)
(Intercept)           x 
  1.0273856   0.9690455 
> sqrt(diag(vcov(m1)))
(Intercept)           x 
  0.044285    0.031726 
> sqrt(diag(vcov(m2)))
(Intercept)           x 
 0.04367438  0.03127408
```

I'm not sure to understand why the standard errors are different in this case. Is this due to statistical theory or to the `gmm()` function ?

See my [gist file](https://gist.github.com/pachevalier/6111962) if you want to run the example.

Comment: I think this is due to 'gmm()' function. The general formula of the s.d. of a GMM estimator depends on the weighting matrix and involves some matrix inverse. There might be slight difference due to computational error.

Answer (score 5):

The standard errors from `lm` **should not** be the same as those from GMM, because the assumptions about the regression errors differ. `lm` assumes homoscedastic regression errors, the `gmm` function does not. **That being said**, the HC consistent standard errors from the `sandwich` package function `vcovHC` *should* be equivalent to two-step GMM starting from and identity matrix. When I run them, they still aren't.

So what can account for differing standard errors among what should be equivalent GMM routines? I wrote up a comprehensive answer to a similar question: [Gradient in GMM estimation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78994/gradient-in-gmm-estimation/108070#108070). In this specific case, the problem is likely with the calculation of the gradient or (less likely) matrix inversion. The numerical gradient used by `gmm` will not perform as well as the direct estimate from the `lm` function.